# Find the Shape's form of a MS Visio in C#

Tags: c#, visio

I must look at every Shape of a visio and determine if it represent a circle.

I don't find a property which allows me to know the form, the radius, or any element in touch with a circle.

Here is a small code :

```
for (var k = 1; k < shapesCount; k++)
{
    var shape = Document.Pages[1].Shapes[k];

    .......

    if( 'element is a circle')
           Console.WriteLine(shape.Name + " est un cercle");
}
```

Sorry for my English, I'm French student.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff766806.aspx

and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160744.aspx

Both articles don't have any sort of direct "test for shape" logic, and I'd suggest (educated guess), that this is because in Visio there's no concept of a "circle" or a "rectangle".

Visio has these "stencils" that allow you to create shapes.

So a circle stencil would be a collection of points that look like a circle, and when the stencil is used, it creates a new `Shape` object that is identical.

Using a stencil seems to be known as a **master** shape, so it's possible you could so something like:

```
Visio.Document visioStencil = visioDocs.OpenEx("Basic Shapes.vss",
(short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);

Visio.Master visioCircleMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Circle");

// Shape code here
var shape = Document.Pages[1].Shapes[0];
var isCircle = shape.Master == visioCircleMaster;
```

I'm not sure this would work, and even if it did it would only work for shapes that are created using that stencil.

If your question is a more generic:

> How do I get the path data of a shape in visio and heuristically determine if it represents a circle?

Then I'm afraid I can't help you there, it may simply not be possible.